# Boo in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, boo

Is there a way to use boo in my msvs? I would like my form to call some boo code instead of C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've been working on a plug-in for a while, it sorta works but you should really use SharpDevelop or MonoDevelop at this point. The VS plugin might get revitalized since the new VS plugin architecture for VS2010 is so much better but it's really a lot of work and we have all been pretty busy.

Comment: Good to know. VS2010 is alive. Any changes? ;)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Boo to replace an old database-driven clunky rules engine, and it's working great.

Start here: [Boo Interactive Interpreter](http://boo.codehaus.org/Interactive+Interpreter)

```
// One-line Boo interpreter in C#
InteractiveInterpreter2 interpreter = new InteractiveInterpreter2();
```

If you mean defining your forms and actually coding Boo in VS .NET, look into [BooLangStudio](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/boo-in-visual-studio.html).

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Boo](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d15c62f-de0d-42f0-863a-daa8330d977a) ([source code](https://github.com/mfeingold/Boo-Plugin)) is a more recent project adding support for Boo in VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your Boo script pop-up a source-readable VS debugger by inserting:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
```

Answer (score 1):

If by msvs you mean visual studio, you would have to write a language plugin for boo (assuming one does not exist) using the Visual Studio Extendability framework.

Here is such a plugin :

http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/boo-in-visual-studio.html